# Can someone help me with a better way to save images in WebForms?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Ok, I have a program that is playing a video from a live ip camera, lets call this "AppVideo".  I have another program that is going to play this video in a webForm, lets call this program "Play Video".

The way I want to play this video in Play Video is save an image from AppVideo every few seconds and display the new image.

So in AppVideo, I'm saving every new frame to a filestream.

Now what I'm trying to do is take the new image from that filestream and save it in an image folder. This is done in Play Video's page Video.aspx.  Then in viewer.aspx the image is displayed.

here is the code for Video.aspx

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace PlayVideo
{
   public partial class Video : System.Web.UI.Page
   {


      protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {


        string saveTo = @"C:where to save image";
        FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(saveTo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(@"C:filestream is saved", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            ReadWriteStream(fs, writeStream);
        }

        Response.Clear();
        Response.TransmitFile("~/images/test.jpg");



      }

    // readStream is the stream you need to read
    // writeStream is the stream you want to write to
    private void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
    {
        int Length = 256;
        Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
        int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        // write the required bytes
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
        }
        readStream.Close();
        writeStream.Close();
    }

   }

}
```

Then here is the code for viewer.aspx:

```
  <head id="Head1" runat="server"> 

  <title></title>   

  <script type="text/javascript" src="refreshImagePage.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div style="height: 60px" id="div1"> 


 <img src="/Video.aspx" id="the_image" alt="" />


 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 //    alert(1)
       function refreshImage() {
 //                  alert(2);
              window.location.reload();

 //         objIMG = document.getElementById('the_image');
 //         objIMG.src = objIMG.src.substr(0, objIMG.src.indexOf('&nocache=')); +'&nocache=' + Math.random();
     //        alert(3);
           }




 $(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(updateImage, 5000);
 })


</script>



</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

if you notice, in the javascript on viewer.aspx I am refreshing the entire page and commented out refreshing just the image.  Refreshing the image wasn't working and I think it is because of how the image is being saved; the function that saves the image from the filestream is in the page load so it only saves the newest image when the page is loaded.  I have been working on this for around 3 weeks and can't think of anything else to try.  Any ideas?  This way works right now, but I don't like that it refreshes the entire page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way to handle this would be to delegate the problem in 2 parts:

1. An image provider, hosted on web server. Currently it is Viewer.aspx (we will come to this later)
2. An image consumer, located on client's browser. Rendered form of Viewer.aspx.

***Part 1***

We can change the image provider from aspx to HTTP Handler

**ImageHandler.ashx**

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="ImageHandler.ashx.cs" Class="TestImageHandler.ImageHandler" %>
```

**ImageHandler.ashx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

namespace TestImageHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Summary description for ImageHandler
    /// </summary>
    public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            var id = context.Request["id"];
            var iId = 0;
            if (id != null && int.TryParse(id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), out iId))
            {
                try
                {
                    RespondForId(iId, context);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    ErrorResponse(context);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                DefaultResponse(context);
            }
        }

        private static void DefaultResponse(HttpContext context)
        {
            var tt = File.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/noId.jpg"));
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(tt);
        }

        private static void ErrorResponse(HttpContext context)
        {
            var tt = File.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/error.jpg"));
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(tt);
        }

        private void RespondForId(int id, HttpContext context)
        {
            var tt = GetImageBytesForId(id); //File.ReadAllBytes(context.Server.MapPath("~/multcust.png"));
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(tt);
        }

        private static byte[] GetImageBytesForId(int id)
        {
            var b = new Bitmap(200, 200);
            byte[] retBytes;
            using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
            {
                g.DrawRectangle(Pens.BurlyWood, 1, 1, 198, 198);
                using (var arialFontLarge = new Font("Arial", 20))
                {
                    g.DrawString(id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), arialFontLarge, Brushes.Black, 5, 100);
                }

                using (var arialFontSmall = new Font("Arial", 10))
                {
                    g.DrawString(string.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd hhmmssffff}", DateTime.Now), arialFontSmall, Brushes.Black, 5, 5);
                }
                var converter = new ImageConverter();
                retBytes = (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(b, typeof(byte[]));
            }
            return retBytes;
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
    }
}
```

***Part 2***

Client side of the application.

**index.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>File Swap</title>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function refreshIt() {
            if (!document.images) return;
            for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
                document.getElementById("imgcontainer" + i).src = "/imagehandler.ashx?id=" + i + "&rand=" + Math.random();
            }
            setTimeout('refreshIt()', 1000);
        }
    </script>
</head>
    <body onload="setTimeout('refreshIt()',1000)">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="imgcontainer1" src="/imagehandler.ashx?id=1" alt="cam image" /></td>
                <td><img id="imgcontainer2" src="/imagehandler.ashx?id=2" alt="cam image" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="imgcontainer3" src="/imagehandler.ashx?id=3" alt="cam image" /></td>
                <td><img id="imgcontainer4" src="/imagehandler.ashx?id=4" alt="cam image" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><img id="imgcontainer5" src="/imagehandler.ashx?id=5" alt="cam image" /></td>
                <td><img id="imgcontainer6" src="/imagehandler.ashx?id=6" alt="cam image" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Update 1: Changed ImageHandler.ashx.cs and index.htm to handle multiple images.

Method `GetImageBytesForId` can be changed to return the correct image depending upon Id, rather than returning the dummy image.

Comment: I added the .ashx file and the .htm files, but I have a couple questions.  what file do I set as the start page? and Do I not have the viewer.aspx and Video.aspx files anymore?  I made the index.htm file as the start page and when I run it it just says "cam image" in a box where the image is supposed to be.  Sorry for the questions, I usually work with winforms, not webforms.

Comment: I changed ImageHandler.ashx.cs to "~/images/test.jpg" and that displays the last image that was saved.  Now the problem is saving the newest image, because the function I have that saves the newest image is in Video.aspx in page load.

Comment: You do not need Viewer or Video files anymore. You can make all the transformations, from fetching frame, obtaining new file etc in ashx.cs file itself.

Comment: Sorry for not getting back to you, I've been busy with other stuff projects.  So would I be able to just add the "ReadWriteStream" function from my Video.aspx file to the .ashx?  otherwise I am not sure how to fetch the new frame.

Comment: Oh my God!!!!! That worked! I added the "ReadWriteStream" function to the .ashx file and it worked!  Thank you so much; I've been working on this for like a month! Well, in between other stuff, but that's only because I couldn't figure this out.

Comment: If I wanted to have multiple pages, each page viewing a different camera, could I do that in one imageHandler?  I'm trying it with multiple ImageHandler pages and it's not displaying the image.

Comment: Yes you can do that in one Image Handler, just need to parse the query string for appropriate image to render.

Comment: How can I make it so that multiple cameras are shown on one page?  I was able to get a page for each camera, but now I want to add a page with multiple cameras.

Comment: I just saw that you updated your post.  That works great!  I did have to add before return retBytes; was "b.Dispose();"  But the drawing image thing you did really helped me with something else too.  Thanks a lot!